Ory Kratos Verification Email has no Code or Link
I have deployed Ory Kratos v1.1.0 in Google Cloud Run successfully, bar one hold up. When I try to complete a verification flow, all goes swimmingly and the email is sent, however the full text of the email is:
Hi, please verify your account by entering the following code: or clicking the following link:

The code and link are missing completely. Here is my config file:
version: v1.0.0

serve:
  public:
    # need to be set with the following env variable
    # SERVE_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
    # base_url: <base_url_here>
    cors:
      enabled: true
      debug: true
      allow_credentials: true
      options_passthrough: true
      max_age: 0
      allowed_origins:
        # need to be set with the following env variable
        # SERVE_PUBLIC_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS_0
        # - <cors_allowed_origin_here>
      allowed_methods:
        - POST
        - GET
        - PUT
        - PATCH
        - DELETE
        - OPTIONS
      allowed_headers:
        - Authorization
        - Cookie
        - Origin
        - X-Session-Token
      exposed_headers:
        - Content-Type
        - Set-Cookie

selfservice:
  # need to be set with the following env variable
  # SELFSERVICE_DEFAULT_BROWSER_RETURN_URL
  # default_browser_return_url: <url_here>
  
  # need to be set with the following env variable
  # SELFSERVICE_ALLOWED_RETURN_URLS_0
  # SELFSERVICE_ALLOWED_RETURN_URLS_1
  # etc.
  # allowed_return_urls:
    # - <url1>
    # - <url2>

  methods:
    password:
      enabled: true
    totp:
      enabled: true
      config:
        issuer: Company Name Here
    link:
      enabled: true
    code:
      enabled: true
      config:
        lifespan: 15m

  flows:
    error:
      # need to be set with the following env variable
      # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_ERROR_UI_URL
      # ui_url: <url>

    settings:
      # need to be set with the following env variable
      # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_SETTINGS_UI_URL
      # ui_url: <url>
      privileged_session_max_age: 15m

    recovery:
      enabled: true
      use: code
      lifespan: 15m
      # need to be set with the following env variable
      # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_RECOVERY_UI_URL
      # ui_url: <url>

    verification:
      enabled: true
      use: code
      # need to be set with the following env variable
      # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_VERIFICATION_UI_URL
      # ui_url: <url>


    # need to be set with the following env variable
    # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_LOGOUT_AFTER_DEFAULT_BROWSER_RETURN_URL
    # logout:
    #   after:
    #     default_browser_return_url: <url>

    login:
      # need to be set with the following env variable
      # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_LOGIN_UI_URL
      # ui_url: <url>
      lifespan: 10m
    registration:
      lifespan: 10m
      # need to be set with the following env variable
      # SELFSERVICE_FLOWS_REGISTRATION_UI_URL
      # ui_url: <url>

log:
  level: debug
  format: text
  leak_sensitive_values: true

# need to be set with the following env variables
# SECRETS_COOKIE_0
# SECRETS_CIPHER_0
# secrets:
#  cookie:
#     - PLEASE-CHANGE-ME-I-AM-VERY-INSECURE
#  cipher:
#     - 32-LONG-SECRET-NOT-SECURE-AT-ALL

ciphers:
  algorithm: xchacha20-poly1305

hashers:
  algorithm: bcrypt
  bcrypt:
    cost: 8

identity:
  schemas:
    - id: default
      url: file:///etc/config/kratos/identity.schema.json

courier:
  smtp:
    from_address: <fromaddress_here>
    from_name: <fromname_here>
# needs to be set with the following env variable
# COURIER_SMTP_CONNECTION_URI
#     connection_uri: <uri-here>


So, I had correctly configured all of my environment variables. The offending lines have to do with the cookie and cypher secrets.
This will not work:
# secrets:
#  cookie:
#     - PLEASE-CHANGE-ME-I-AM-VERY-INSECURE
#  cipher:
#     - 32-LONG-SECRET-NOT-SECURE-AT-ALL

This will work, given that you have properly configured the SECRETS_COOKIE_0 and SECRETS_CIPHER_0 environment variables:
secrets:
 cookie:
#     - PLEASE-CHANGE-ME-I-AM-VERY-INSECURE
 cipher:
#     - 32-LONG-SECRET-NOT-SECURE-AT-ALL

